# Run INSERT INTO statement without parameters

Tags: c#, sql

I currently have a functional `INSERT INTO` statement, on a button click, that works perfectly fine. Due to additional requirements for this project, I have a second `INSERT INTO` query that works but now I need both of them to work in conjunction with one another. How do I take both INSERT queries and make them just one `INSERT INTO` statement because the other way is duplicating rows (which is expect because of adding the two new columns). I have posted the following queries below:

Current `INSERT INTO` from gridview into an Informix database:

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
OdbcDataAdapter da2 = new OdbcDataAdapter();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
String insertData = "INSERT INTO brev_efile_user_doc_stats (trans_nbr, sequence_id, received_on, description, register_action) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(insertData, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trans_nbr", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sequence_id", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@received_on", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@register_action", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);

  da2.InsertCommand = cmd;

  try
    {
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Second `INSERT INTO` used to display corrected sequence from XML (which isn't always correct):

```
INSERT INTO brev_efile_user_doc_stats
SELECT trans_nbr,received_on,description,register_action,sequence_id, reviewed_event_code,     
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY trans_nbr 
ORDER BY trans_nbr,sequence_id) AS corrected_seq_id
FROM brev_efile_user_doc_stats
WHERE trans_nbr IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY trans_nbr,sequence_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to accomplish the insert in one statement by using a UNION ALL.  Just make sure that your first select has the same number of columns (parameters in this case) as the second select statement.  I added additional parameters for @reviewed_event_code and @corrected_seq_id.  You will need to set the parameter values the same way you are setting the other parameter values on your ODBCCommand object.  I hope this helps!

```
INSERT INTO brev_efile_user_doc_stats
SELECT @trans_nbr, @received_on, @description, @register_action, @sequence_id, @reviewed_event_code, @corrected_seq_id
UNION ALL
SELECT trans_nbr,received_on,description,register_action,sequence_id, reviewed_event_code,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY trans_nbr ORDER BY trans_nbr, received_on) AS corrected_seq_id
FROM brev_efile_user_doc_stats
WHERE trans_nbr IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY trans_nbr,corrected_seq_id
```

Comment: how exactly would that work with the Values() that are being obtained from the datagridview table?

Comment: I'm not sure I contextually fully understand the underlying problem that you are trying to solve, but that statement would substitute in your gridview row parameter values, and then insert all of the additional records being selected from the brev_efile_user_doc_stats table.  Perhaps this would not solve your underlying problem.  Sorry about that

Comment: this XML is a nightmare to extract data from. the sequence numbering is never 1,2,3. I have seen it do 1,9,10. basically, I am forcing the sequence per the duplicates records (if they exist) for how many times "trans_nbr" shows up